# Is this function actually continuous at x=1?

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

my professor gave a solution to the given problem but i am unsure how the answer got to be -1 since the original function is f(x)=2x^3 -1 and not f(x)=-2x^3-1. is he correct?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmA8R.jpg

Comment: I think there's a mistake in the hand-written part. $f(-1)$ should be $f(-1) = -3$. And indeed you have spotted it yourself. It's
$$
2(-1)^3 -1 
$$
and not
$$
-2(-1)^3 -1
$$

Comment: ... though $-3$ is also the limit as $f(x)\to -3$ as $x \to -1$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Also, just as a side note, all polynomials are continuous.

Answer (score 1):

You are right. There is a transfer error in the handwritten part.